# vscode autocomplete in private package import do not working python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, package

Vscode autocomplete do not working when i import my private package from git and shows this message error on code line: `Unable to import 'elixir_tools' pylint(import-error)`

my setup.py structure:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='elixir_tools',
    url='***',
    author='Elixir AI',
    author_email='***',
    packages=[
        'elixir_tools',
        'elixir_tools.executors',
        'elixir_tools.models',
        'elixir_tools.transforms',
        'elixir_tools.utils'
    ],
    install_requires=[
        'pandas',
        'numpy',
        'datetime',
        'xlrd',
        'psycopg2-binary',
        'flask_bcrypt',
        'flake8',
        'bayesian-optimization',
        'scikit-learn',
        'python-dateutil',
        'xgboost',
        'croston',
        'pytest'
    ],
    version='0.1',
    license='MIT',
)
```

any suggestion?

Edit1: 
The package directory has this structure:

```
repo
|_ elixir_tools
|   |_ executors
|   |_ models
|   |_ transforms
|   |_ utils
|
|_ setup.cfg
|_ setup.py
```

Comment: Where is the source for `elixir_tools` being kept? Is it implemented in C? Basically Pylint can't find the code so it's saying it can't be imported.

Comment: @BrettCannon It is being kept on gitlab, see edit1. Is implemented in Python and installed with pip from a gitlab repository. When i import the elixir_tools package on another project vscode shows me this error message, but the code works.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I installed the elixir_tools package in a different env than the updated pylint, removing both packages and installing again with pip in the same env worked perfectly.